# Google App Script - Make the checkboxes unchecked after a reset button is clicked

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

So I have a sheet where I added a Custom Menu (that I have searched and found in google).

The Custom Menu shows a dialog (see image below) It returns all the data validation I have in a specific cell, each of which has a checkbox so I can select multiple options and return it in a single cell.

[image]

My problem is, I need to have a reset button wherein when clicked, all the items checked previously will be unchecked.

I used this code below:

```
<input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="google.script.run.showDialog();" />
```

which is, I think, the code for loading the data validation, so maybe it reruns the whole dialog and so, the loading time is really taking a while (it's so slow!).

Can someone please help me to solve this? Thank you so much!

Comment: Have you tried [Range.uncheck()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#uncheck())?

Comment: It doesnt work ;(

Comment: Omg I have found the solution. I just used onclick="reset()"